# Create another comment system for CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, comments

Noob here.

I've created a "giveaway" post type and launched couple times of Giveaway campaigns on my website with default comment system by this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pick-giveaway-winner/

This plugin randomly draft users who commentted below in a giveaway post. In my case, I asked the participants to leave their phone number for contacting.
Here comes a problem when I modifying my theme recently. I am considering to turn on "Recent Comments" widget in the sidebar, however, it expose their personal information.

Is there any method for me to create exclusive comment system for my giveaway custom post type?

Sincerely,

Lai.

Comment: So your problem is that the recent comments widget shows comments on posts of all types, and you want to filter it to those of a specific type, why don't you ask about that instead? The concept of an "exclusive comment system" doesn't make a lot of sense in WordPress

Comment: Exactly, you are right. Creating a filter might be better. I'd googled it up.